# Autowiring Beans in a SpringBoot Application

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection

Currently, the bean that I would like to autowire is returning a nullpointerException.

Here's the Application class:

```
package com.springbootapp.jerseyws;
.
.
.


  @SpringBootApplication
    public class JerseywsApplication {

    @Bean
    public CountryService countryService() {
        return new CountryService();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JerseywsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here's the controller:

```
package com.springbootapp.jerseyws.controller;
.
.
.
    @Path("/country")
    public class CountryController {

    @Autowired
    private CountryService countryService;

    public CountryController() {
        //countryService = new CountryService();
    }

    @Path("list")
    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public List<Country> getCountries() {
        return countryService.getCountries(); // <------ countryService is null
    }
}
```

And here's the country service:

```
package com.springbootapp.jerseyws.service;
.
.
.
    @Service
    public class CountryService {

    public List<Country> getCountries() {
        Country c1 = new Country("USA", 320);
        Country c2 = new Country("Norway", 6);
        Country c3 = new Country("Sweden", 10);
        List<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<>();
        countryList.add(c1);
        countryList.add(c2);
        countryList.add(c3);
        return countryList;
    }
}
```

This example is annotation-based. There's something missing because the bean that I'm trying to instantiate through the `@Autowired` annotation is null.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller needs `@RestController` annotation, or it will not injected in spring context. If a class in not part of spring context, it cannot have `@Autowired` classes.

```
@Path("/country")
@RestController
public class CountryController {
```

remove also

```
@Bean
public CountryService countryService() {
    return new CountryService();
}
```

you don't need it

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it didn't fix the nullpointer exception. I must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: remove `@Bean` and if not fixed, add packages of each class, probably `@SpringBootApplication` cannot read components to inject

Comment: Removing the @Bean annotation didn't fix the problem, but thanks for pointing out that it wasn't necessary. I also added the packages.

Answer (score 0):

try removing below snippet from controller class. there is no need for an empty constructor, if you've already annotated the controller with @restcontroller

```
public CountryController() {
    //countryService = new CountryService();
}
```